# Inventory bug in "Diplomatic Immunity"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't get my items at the chest inside the embassy. Please help how to fix this bug.

Comment: We could use a bit more info. Can you see them but not take them? Can you not open the chest? Have you talked to Malborn? Has he distracted the kitchen staff yet?

Comment: Yes, the door was locked. I opened the chest and my items are not there. It's the optional quest to retrieve my gear.

Comment: Have you talked to Malborn?

Comment: I think I am.. I tried to load it again and still don't get my gear.

Comment: ... You think you are what? ... Okay, can you just tell us what you've done to get to the chest? Tell us a story, and maybe we'll be able to see what's going wrong. If you don't tell us *more* we can't help you.

Comment: hahaha.. I am an idiot. Sorry to bother you guys. I really thought that I would get my weapons, items, apparels there but as I repeat the quest I don't really know that I have to give Malborn the items I want to smuggle inside the embassy. I just skipped everything what he said. Lesson learned.:)

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak You should post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mistakenly thought that I would get my weapons, items and clothing inside the embassy. As I repeat the quest it is clear that it is not necessary to give Malborn the items I want to smuggle inside (which I had thought was a requirement).